# Cannot create CPA for Mobile Install Ads

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to create a Mobile Install App ad with CPA but I get this error:

> (Exception - #1487807) You cannot use CPA bidding for the given ad creative.

The error indicates there is something wrong with the Creative but it's pretty simple:

> object_store_url=https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id383825543
>
> image_hash=234af8013a712194de33df7866bf0cc4
>
> body=Install this App

Could this error be thrown because the account doesn't have enough mobile installations for this application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Facebook fixed this bug yesterday:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1410170489249153/

Now I'm getting the following error, which explain the situation better:

> (Exception - #1487579) Your account does not have enough install history to start using cost per action (CPA) bidding for mobile app install ads. Please visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/cost-per-action-ads/ to learn more.